# Improving performance of highlighting [every line]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on code-editor (winforms) and I use token parameters for highlighting such as:

```
     foreach (string token in tokens)
            {
                // Set the token's default color and font.
                rtb.SelectionStart = index;
                rtb.SelectionLength = token.Length;
                rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                rtb.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
    
                if (rtb != null)
                {
                    //pass through to the HighlightType class
                    HighlighType HighlighType = new HighlighType(rtb);
                    lb.Hide();
                    lb.Items.Clear();   
                }
    
                if (token == "//" || token.StartsWith("//"))
                {
                    // Find the start of the comment and then extract the whole comment.
                    int length = line.Length - (index - start);
                    string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
                    rtb.SelectionStart = index;
                    rtb.SelectionLength = length;
                    HighlighType.commentsType(rtb);
                    break;
                }

var keywordsDef = new KeyWord();
            String[] keywords = keywordsDef.keywords;

            for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (keywords[i] == token)
                {
                    // Apply alternative color and font to highlight keyword.        
                    HighlighType.keywordsType(rtb);

                    toolTip1.Show("this is a keyword", rtb); //&
                    break;
                }
            }

if (token == "letterA" || token.StartsWith("ab") || token.StartsWith("Ab") || token.StartsWith("AB"))
            {
                int length = line.Length - (index - start);
                string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
                rtb.SelectionStart = index;
                rtb.SelectionLength = length;
                lb.Visible = true;
                int i = commentText.IndexOf(token);

                KeyWord_Ab newCode = new KeyWord_Ab();

              

            }
```

inside a textchanged event.

But every time I press "space" the all text from line of cursor highlights something like this:

[image]

Highlighting already worked but the problem was it was like scanning every text to be highlighting in a line.

What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to interpret since we don't know anything about HighlighType class, which seems to be doing all of the work.  Use the debugger to tackle the selection issue where is set the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties.

Comment: @LarsTech i think its the selectionstart and length sir which i need to improve :/ likewhat youve said . but i dunno how to improve its performance:/